# Postgres on wsl

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed and run postgresql 9.6 on windows 10 .
When I am trying to run a bash script containing `psql` from Ubuntu terminal, I get:

```
Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package.
```

My Ubuntu path contains all enviromental variables from Windows, including `postgresql` bin.
`psql` commands are not available .

Is there any way to make Ubuntu understand that there is a postgres installation on Windows running?

Answer (score -1):

You must install at least `postgresql-client-common`.